# Strange html-structure shift in specific joomla-page

Tags: joomla-3.4

I have a strange problem with the html-structure of following joomla-page:

http://tnav.mascomm.be/evenementen

The sidebar has been pushed to the far left (not visible on small screen sizes), and the footer is much smaller than it used to be.

It used to look exactly like this page http://tnav.mascomm.be/nieuws , but the structure somehow changed. When I looked at the structure with the firebug tool I have a better idea of the problem:

The `<body>` used to look like this (rough structure):

```
<body>
<div class="t3-wrapper">
    <div id="t3-mainbody">
        <div id="t3-content">…</div>
        <div class="t3-sidebar">…</div>
    </div>
    <div id="t3-footnav">…</div>
</div>
</body>
```

But now, without making any fundamental changes (as far as I know, maybe our customer messed around in the backend?) , it looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="t3-wrapper">
    <div id="t3-mainbody">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="t3-content">
                <div class="t3-sidebar">…</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="t3-footnav">…</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

SUMMARY:

- `#t3-mainbody` and `#t3-footnav` used to have the same level in the html-hierarchy, but now `#t3-footnav` is inside of `#t3-mainbody`.
- `#t3-content` and `.t3-sidebar` used to have the same level in the hierarchy , but now `.t3-sidebar` is inside `#t3-content`.

Both pages have a different structure, although the same template is assigned to them. Does anyone have any idea what happened here and what may be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unclosed div element on the first page as you can check with this tool:
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ftnav.mascomm.be%2Fevenementen

Comment: Thanks. Nice tool! Do you know how I can solve it? Because in Joomla the I can't access the html code. It's generated by php or something, and I don't know much about php.

Comment: Well... there is no easy way to find the missing div which I am aware of. But if you did not change anything in the template (PHP) then probably someone entered (broken) HTML code into the WYSIWYG editor? For example in an article or a custom module?

Comment: Found it! the customer placed an unclosed div inside one of the articles. Probably from copying the text from another site. Thank you very much for the help!